# Need Help Returning Data From HTML Form on New HTML Page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm having a bit of trouble with something I'm sure most of you will laugh at.

I have a form built into one HTML page (contact.html), and I need to have a second HTML page (submit.html) display the information entered into the form using JavaScript. Here is my form code from page 1:

```
<form name="contact" method="post" action="submit.html">
    <p>First Name: *</p><input type="text" name="first">
    <p>Last Name: *</p><input type="text" name="last">
    <p>Cell Phone Number:</p><input type="text" name="number">
    <p>E-mail Address: *</p><input type="text" name="address">
    <p>Comment: *</p>
    <p><textarea name="comments" cols="25" rows="5">
</textarea></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
    </form>
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction? I'm literally brand new to JavaScript, so I don't understand much of any of it yet.

Thank you in advance, and please take it easy on me!

Answer (score 0):

You can't get post parameters using javascript - post parameters are going through the headers in a hidden way and you have to set your second page to be some server side page (php,asp.net etc...)
In php for example you can get post parameters using this:

```
$first_value = $_POST['first'];
```

If you still want to use only javascript you can change your method of the form to "get" (`method="get"`) and then the parameters will be in the URL - and then in the other page you can use a regexp to take the get params using this function:

```
function getQSParam(key,target){
    var value = '';
    if(!target){
        target = location.href;
    }

    var pattern = key + '=([^&]+)';
    var o_reg = new RegExp(pattern,'i');
    var matches = o_reg.exec(target);
    if(matches && matches[1]){
        value = matches[1];
    }

    return value;
}
```

So if the url will be like that: submit.html?first=karl&last=marx&...
you can take those parameters using the function like that:

```
var first_value = getQSParam('first');
var last_value = getQSParam('last');
```

and so on...